# Locate Nested Directories And Files Dynamically In Qt5/QML

Tags: javascript, file, qml, qt5, filepath

I have a QML application with a C++ Qt backend that is using Qt 5.12.6.

I have a txt file in the path below:
"C:/Users//Documents/ParentDir/ChildDir/FinalTarget.txt"

As for several design purposes I need to reach these files under the standard DocumentsLocation.

I am trying to locate the FinalTarget.txt in a non hardcoded way in my Qml application (I don't want to hard code the absolute path of the file). I have logged the results of the locating processes as below:

```
console.log("RESULT1= " + StandardPaths.displayName(1));
console.log("RESULT2= " + StandardPaths.locate(1, "ParentDir", 1));
```

I am currently receiving the below results as logs in the Application Output:

```
qml: RESULT1= Documents
qml: RESULT2= file:///C:/Users/<MY_USER_NAME>/Documents/ParentDir
```

How can I reach the ChildDir and ultimately FinalTarget.txt since I am aiming to reach to the FinalTarget.txt in my application and do file IO processes such as reading and writing.

It would be really kind if someone could help me by showing me the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the following code

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("RESULT1= " + StandardPaths.displayName(StandardPaths.DocumentsLocation));
    console.log("RESULT2= " + StandardPaths.locate(StandardPaths.DocumentsLocation, "ParentDir/ChildDir/FinalTarget.txt", StandardPaths.LocateFile));
}
```

prints

```
qml: RESULT1= Documents
qml: RESULT2= file:///home/mitch/Documents/ParentDir/ChildDir/FinalTarget.txt
```

and fails if the file doesn't exist. So it seems that the `fileName` argument can be a relative path.

Though I am curious why you'd want to do this from QML, since it has no API to do file IO, so you'd have to do it in C++ anyway.

Comment: The part where I needed to do IO processes was a temporary task so I wanted to keep it as simple as it can be by not creating additional .cpp files. But after some research I have reached on the same conclusion about QML having no API for file IO and this kind of operations could be done via cpp in a smoother way. Thanks for the answer by the way.